# Will Google AdSense penalize me for having an image with the word "beer" in it?

Tags: seo, google, google-adsense

I have a website with this image that has the name: "biodegradable-beer-packaging".

I do not sell beer or any alcohol products, but will Google still penalize me for using it?

Will search engines categorize my website as one that is selling alcohol products?

Comment: Google AdSense content policies about alcohol can be found here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9335567#alcohol_sale_and_misuse   I'm not sure if biodegradable-beer-packaging would fall under the "facilitates the online sale of alcoholic beverages" clause, or not.